# Why is the non-linear wave equation $u_{tt} = \operatorname{div}(a(Du))$ quasi-linear?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I came across the PDE

\begin{align*}
u_{tt} - \operatorname{div}(a(Du)) = 0
\end{align*}
where $a:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $Du$ is the gradient of the unknown $u$ and $\operatorname{div}(\cdot) = \operatorname{trace}(D\,\cdot)$ and I'm not seeing why it should be quasi-linear. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: I read it in some Uni notes, being rather a side note and not a proof; my understanding of *quasi-linear* is that the coefficient functions of the highest degree derivates only depend on $x,y,..$, on lower degree derivates of $u$ or on $u$

Comment: OK, if we want to extend this definition to the present equation, then we need the coefficients of the highest derivatives also dependent on $Du$, cf. answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Chain_rule) gives
\begin{aligned}
\text{div}\big(a(Du)\big) &= [a_{i}(u_{,j}\,{\bf e}_j)]_{,i} \\ 
&= a_{i,k}(u_{,j}\,{\bf e}_j)\, u_{,ki}\\
& = \text{tr}\big( J_a(Du)\, DDu \big)
\end{aligned}
where $J_a$ is the Jacobian matrix of $a$ (note that Einstein notation was used). Because of the resemblance of
$$
u_{tt} - \text{tr}\big(J_a(Du)\, DDu\big) = 0
$$
with the linear wave equation $u_{tt} - \Delta u = 0$ where $\Delta$ denotes the Laplace operator, we may call *quasi-linear* this form of the present nonlinear wave equation. Note that the linear wave equation $u_{tt} - \Delta u = 0$ is recovered if $a = \text{id} + c$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant vector.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Do you mean by $u_{,j} = u_{x_j} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}$?

Comment: @MJimitater Yes, forgot to mention it. Summation on repeated indices is also omitted ([Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation))

Comment: Thanks @EditPiAf! My difficulty was to simply apply the chain rule consistently, but thanks to your help, all is clear! Cheers!